# Why does my vba script work when executed line by line (in debug), but not when running it?

Tags: vba, ms-word

A friend of mine needs a script for Microsoft Word - and I created a script... but it has some really odd error... :)
Meaning - it works when I run it on Debug [line by line], but when I Run it as a whole script... it just doesn't do it...

It could be something with the "Searching part" - as, when run normally, it simply stays at the first find and keeps replacing the text there, over and over. But - surprisingly for me - it does work when it is run line by line, under debugging's "Step" option...

It should search for some text in a document, store it in some string arrays, then replace the needed text in some other (opened already) document...
[in order to insert the needed text in the right place, I'm searching for some specific text, then moving the cursor a little, then inserting the text]

It's actually replacing the bible books names of the references, from one language to another.

Links:
script - https://paste.ee/p/P7nqv
documents - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xPcFesAQZ1Zal1XWAmhOCMMTEr1WWkGP

Here's the script:

```
Public oneyearbible(31) As String
Public twoyearbible(31) As String
Public furtherstudy(31) As String
Public cateziletrebuie As Integer


Sub extractandfixverses()
    Dim pathName, numefisier As String
    Dim acatazi, zisaptamana, ziua, lunacurenta, ancurent, annecesar, lunanecesara, lunaplus As Integer
    Dim documente, rapsodie, rhapsody As Document
    Dim numedocorig, tempstring, whichmonth As String
    Dim i, n As Integer
    Dim rapsodieorig As Boolean

    For i = 1 To 31
        furtherstudy(i) = ""
        oneyearbible(i) = ""
        twoyearbible(i) = ""
    Next

    rapsodieorig = False
    rapsodie = ActiveDocument
    n = Application.Documents.Count
    lunacurenta = Val(Format(Now, "mm"))
    ancurent = Val(Format(Now, "yyyy"))
    numefisier = ActiveDocument.Name
    lunanecesara = lunadec(numefisier)
    If lunacurenta > lunanecesara Then
        annecesar = ancurent + 1
    Else
        annecesar = ancurent
    End If
    acatazi = DatePart("y", Date)
    cateziletrebuie = Val(Format(DateSerial(annecesar, lunanecesara + 1, 0), "dd"))

    whichmonth = monthname(lunanecesara)
    For Each documente In Application.Documents
        tempstring = UCase(documente.Name)
        If ((Not (InStr(tempstring, whichmonth) = 0)) _
            And (Not (InStr(tempstring, "INNER") = 0)) _
            And (Not (InStr(tempstring, "LAYOUT") = 0))) Then
                numedocorig = documente.Name
                Set rhapsody = documente
                rapsodieorig = True
        End If
    Next documente
    If rapsodieorig Then
        Documents(rhapsody).Activate
    Else
        MsgBox ("Rapsodia originala, in engleza, in format doc, nu este deschisa!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Selection.InsertBefore Text:="test new text "

    'ActiveDocument.Content.InsertBefore Text:="test The beginning."
    'ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:="test The end."

    Call gaitherverses

    Documents(rapsodie).Activate

    Call fixverses







End Sub


Sub gaitherverses()
    Dim ziua As Integer

    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    ziua = 0
    Do While ziua < cateziletrebuie
        ziua = ziua + 1
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Text = "FURTHER STUDY"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.MoveDown
        Selection.HomeKey
        With Selection.Find
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Text = "[a-zA-Z]"  '[A-Z] if you only want upper case
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.HomeKey
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        furtherstudy(ziua) = replacebooknames(Selection.Text)

        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Text = "1-YEAR BIBLE READING PLAN"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.MoveDown
        Selection.HomeKey
        With Selection.Find
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Text = "[a-zA-Z]"  '[A-Z] if you only want upper case
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.HomeKey
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        oneyearbible(ziua) = replacebooknames(Selection.Text)



        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Text = "2-YEAR BIBLE READING PLAN"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.MoveDown
        Selection.HomeKey
        With Selection.Find
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Text = "[a-zA-Z]"  '[A-Z] if you only want upper case
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.HomeKey
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

        twoyearbible(ziua) = replacebooknames(Selection.Text)
    Loop

    MsgBox (oneyearbible(ziua - 2) & oneyearbible(ziua - 1) & oneyearbible(ziua))

End Sub

Function replacebooknames(ByVal booknamesin As String) As String
    Dim wrdsarray() As String
    Dim resulte, tempstring As String
    Dim i As Integer

    resulted = ""
    wrdsarray() = Split(booknamesin)
    resulted = convertbiblebooks(wrdsarray(LBound(wrdsarray)))
    For i = (LBound(wrdsarray) + 1) To UBound(wrdsarray)
        tempstring = convertbiblebooks(wrdsarray(i))
        Select Case tempstring
            Case "SKIP_WORD"
                resulted = resulted
            Case Else
                resulted = resulted & tempstring
        End Select
    Next i
replacebooknames = Application.CleanString(resulted)
End Function

Function convertbiblebooks(ByVal bookname As String) As String
    Dim booknameup, skipword, rezultat As String
    skipword = "SKIP_WORD"
    booknameup = UCase(bookname)
    'booknameup = Replace(booknameup, Chr(59), "")
    Select Case booknameup
    Case "GENESIS"
        rezultat = "Geneza"
    Case "EXODUS"
        rezultat = "Exod"
    Case "LEVITICUS"
        rezultat = "Levitic"
    Case "NUMBERS"
        rezultat = "Numeri"
    Case "DEUTERONOMY"
        rezultat = "Deuteronom"
    Case "JOSHUA"
        rezultat = "Iosua"
    Case "JUDGES"
        rezultat = "Judec" & ChrW(259) & "tori"
    Case "RUTH"
        rezultat = "Rut"
    Case "SAMUEL"
        rezultat = "Samuel"
    Case "KINGS"
        rezultat = "Împ" & ChrW(259) & "ra" & ChrW(539) & "i"
    Case "CHRONICLES"
        rezultat = "Cronici"
    Case "EZRA"
        rezultat = "Ezra"
    Case "NEHEMIAH"
        rezultat = "Neemia"
    Case "ESTHER"
        rezultat = "Estera"
    Case "JOB"
        rezultat = "Iov"
    Case "PSALMS"
        rezultat = "Psalmii"
    Case "PROVERBS"
        rezultat = "Proverbe"
    Case "ECCLESIASTES"
        rezultat = "Eclesiastul"
    Case "SONG"
        rezultat = "C" & ChrW(226) & "ntarea C" & ChrW(226) & "nt" & ChrW(259) & "rilor"
    Case "SONGS"
        rezultat = "C" & ChrW(226) & "ntarea C" & ChrW(226) & "nt" & ChrW(259) & "rilor"
    Case "ISAIAH"
        rezultat = "Isaia"
    Case "JEREMIAH"
        rezultat = "Ieremia"
    Case "LAMENTATIONS"
        rezultat = "Pl" & ChrW(226) & "ngerile lui Ieremia"
    Case "EZEKIEL"
        rezultat = "Ezechiel"
    Case "DANIEL"
        rezultat = "Daniel"
    Case "HOSEA"
        rezultat = "Osea"
    Case "JOEL"
        rezultat = "Ioel"
    Case "AMOS"
        rezultat = "Amos"
    Case "OBADIAH"
        rezultat = "Obadia"
    Case "JONAH"
        rezultat = "Iona"
    Case "MICAH"
        rezultat = "Mica"
    Case "NAHUM"
        rezultat = "Naum"
    Case "HABAKKUK"
        rezultat = "Habacuc"
    Case "ZEPHANIAH"
        rezultat = ChrW(538) & "efania"
    Case "HAGGAI"
        rezultat = "Hagai"
    Case "ZECHARIAH"
        rezultat = "Zaharia"
    Case "MALACHI"
        rezultat = "Maleahi"
    Case "MATTHEW"
        rezultat = "Matei"
    Case "MARK"
        rezultat = "Marcu"
    Case "LUKE"
        rezultat = "Luca"
    Case "JOHN"
        rezultat = "Ioan"
    Case "ACTS"
        rezultat = "Faptele Apostolilor"
    Case "ROMANS"
        rezultat = "Romani"
    Case "CORINTHIANS"
        rezultat = "Corinteni"
    Case "GALATIANS"
        rezultat = "Galateni"
    Case "EPHESIANS"
        rezultat = "Efeseni"
    Case "PHILIPPIANS"
        rezultat = "Filipeni"
    Case "COLOSSIANS"
        rezultat = "Coloseni"
    Case "THESSALONIANS"
        rezultat = "Tesaloniceni"
    Case "TIMOTHY"
        rezultat = "Timotei"
    Case "TITUS"
        rezultat = "Tit"
    Case "PHILEMON"
        rezultat = "Filimon"
    Case "HEBREWS"
        rezultat = "Evrei"
    Case "JAMES"
        rezultat = "Iacov"
    Case "PETER"
        rezultat = "Petru"
    Case "JUDE"
        rezultat = "Iuda"
    Case "REVELATION"
        rezultat = "Apocalipsa"
    Case "NKJV;", "AMP;", "AMPC;", "TANT;", _
            "TLB;", "CEV;", "NASB;", "ISV;", "NIV;", _
            "MSG;", "WEB;", "TNLT;", "ASV;", _
            "TEV;", "RSV;", "GNB;", "WNT;", _
            "NRSV;", "MOFFAT;", "WESNT;"
        rezultat = ";"
    Case "NKJV", "AMP", "AMPC", "TANT", _
            "TLB", "CEV", "NASB", "ISV", "NIV", _
            "MSG", "WEB", "TNLT", "ASV", _
            "TEV", "RSV", "GNB", "WNT", _
            "NRSV", "MOFFAT", "WESNT"
        rezultat = skipword
    Case Else
        rezultat = bookname
    End Select
    Select Case rezultat
        Case skipword, ";"
            rezultat = rezultat
        Case Else
            rezultat = Chr(32) & rezultat
    End Select
convertbiblebooks = rezultat
End Function

Function monthname(ByVal careluna As Integer) As String
    Select Case careluna
        Case 1
            monthname = "JANUARY"
        Case 2
            monthname = "FEBRUARY"
        Case 3
            monthname = "MARCH"
        Case 4
            monthname = "APRIL"
        Case 5
            monthname = "MAY"
        Case 6
            monthname = "JUNE"
        Case 7
            monthname = "JULY"
        Case 8
            monthname = "AUGUST"
        Case 9
            monthname = "SEPTEMBER"
        Case 10
            monthname = "OCTOBER"
        Case 11
            monthname = "NOVEMBER"
        Case 12
            monthname = "DECEMBER"
    End Select
End Function

Sub fixverses()
    Dim ziua As Integer

    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    ziua = 0
    Do While ziua < cateziletrebuie
        ziua = ziua + 1
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Text = "STUDIU SUPLIMENTAR"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.MoveDown
        Selection.HomeKey
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        'Selection.TypeBackspace
        With Selection.Range
             .Text = furtherstudy(ziua)
        End With
        'Selection.InsertBefore furtherstudy(ziua)

        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Text = "PLAN DE CITIRE A BIBLIEI " & ChrW(206) & "NTR-UN AN"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.MoveDown
        Selection.HomeKey
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        'Selection.TypeBackspace
        'Selection.InsertAfter oneyearbible(ziua)
        With Selection.Range
            .Text = oneyearbible(ziua)
        End With


        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Text = "PLAN DE CITIRE A BIBLIEI " & ChrW(206) & "N DOI ANI"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.MoveDown
        Selection.HomeKey
        Selection.TypeText twoyearbible(ziua)
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.TypeBackspace
        'With Selection.Range
        '    .Text = twoyearbible(ziua)
        'End With

    Loop

    MsgBox (oneyearbible(ziua - 2) & oneyearbible(ziua - 1) & oneyearbible(ziua))





End Sub
```

Just in case - here are the 2 documents on which I am running the script
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xPcFesAQZ1Zal1XWAmhOCMMTEr1WWkGP

Comment: Please give a [mcve] (with an emphasis on "Minimal"). Few people have the patience to wade through hundreds of lines of code looking for a bug. This is a question/answer site, not a debugging service.

Comment: Thanks for your input! As I see it, the "verifiable" example would be in the second phrase of the first paragraph I wrote, specifically, here: "it works when I run it on Debug [line by line], but when I Run it as a whole script... it just doesn't do it..." It's not a debugging request... but it is, indeed, a question about debugging [on Ms-Word's VBA]. Specifically, what could cause a script to work if run under "Debug", but to not work if run normally. I'm sorry about the "minimal" part... I dunno how to make it smaller. I'll try to add a paragraph to express why I guess it happens!... Thanks

Comment: If 400+ lines of code isn't relevant to your question, why post it? In any event, look at things in your code which are context dependent. Perhaps `ActiveDocument` might mean something different when the code is run in different contexts. Perhaps some of your object references aren't fully qualified. Maybe there is a timing issue. If you are stepping through the code line by line then you are stepping through the code slowly. When run at normal speed, perhaps some asynchronous operation isn't completed in time. The problem is buried somewhere in 400 lines of code, but where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script works perfectly. I was applying it onto a wrong document, sorry!... :)
Thanks all and have a nice day everyone!...